# Disable Category Link

Tags: categories, redirect, links, slug

I need some help to disable my category pages and make them not clicable.

[image: Question]

I need to disable those 2nd level slugs from going to another page.I just want them there for structure reasons, no need to be clicable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is just a dirty solution to your unique problem, you can use CSS to disable clicking by using `pointer-events: none;` to those elements.